# how to pass a variable(external js) to variable (internal javascript)

Tags: javascript

external js

```
var vehicle="car";
```

internal js

```
var x;
```

How can I save the external js value "vehicle" in "x" directly.

I not want to use the method of passing the value into any id (eg: input text, paragraph ..).Kindly asking the method for passing it directly.

Comment: Is `var vehicle` a global variable in external js file?

Comment: Include the first script in your page, and then do `var x = vehicle`.

Answer (score 1):

Declare your `vehicle` variable globally. So you can access it in other js files.

```
//external.js
var vehicle = 'car';

<script src="external.js"></script>
<script>
 var x = vehicle;
 console.log(x);
</script>
```

I **do not recommend** using global variables, if you accidentally name a private variable as `vehicle` your global variable value gets overwritten by the private variable inside the function etc.

Learn the [best practices of JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jS/js_best_practices.asp).